# Is there support for arithmetic operations on big integers in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, I can implement the factorial function as follows:

```
fun factorial(n: int): int =
  if n > 0 then n * factorial(n-1) else n
```

Calling `factorial` on 100, I obtain 0 due to integer overflow. I need a type for big integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [unlimited precision `intinf` types](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/LIBRARY/contrib/libats-/hwxi/intinf/SATS/DOCUGEN/HTML/intinf.html), based on the GMP library. See [this example](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/blob/master/utils/atsreloc/TEST/test02.dats) for an `intinf`-based factorial function.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API in ATS for various functions in the GMP library. And the package atscntrb-hx-intinf is a convenience wrap around this API. Please see the following example for further details:

https://github.com/ats-lang/ATS-CodeBook/tree/master/RECIPE/HX-intinf